# SWXMLHash Issue in Swift

Tags: swift, ampersand, swxmlhash

I am using SWXMLHash for parsing the data from server. It crashes when I have &amp in my data.

```
let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let str = responseString as! String
let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(str)
//let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
print("responseString = \(xml)")
```

It does not parse the whole data. It stops where there is &amp or &.

Comment: I've never had this kind of issue with [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi), it may be worth trying.

Comment: Are you sure I wont have any problem? Because I will have to change it in the whole project. I just came through this problem.

Comment: Well I certainly don't suggest to change all your codebase without testing first. :) I would make a new test project, include Fuzi, and simply use it quickly to parse your data and see if it works. If it works better than SWXMLHash (I suppose so but I have no *proof*) then you can change your actual project. Don't forget to use Git and to also backup first, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much... I will test it first with my data.

Comment: I checked it. It does not crash but it is inserting space instead of & :(

Comment: Ampersands shouldn't cause any issues with SWXMLHash... are you sure it isn't some other character? BOM (byte order marks) do have problems with `NSXMLParser` which is what SWXMLHash uses.

Comment: I didn't try NSXMLParser. But yes, the issue was with & Only.

Comment: You might try passing data directly to SWXMLHash like SWXMLHash.parse(data!) or better yet guard let data = data else { return } SWXMLHash.parse(data)

Comment: I have tried this as well.